# How to get the Process Serial Number for an external process under MacOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am reading keys from a Logitech G13 keyboard and need to send them to a known application. It seems I should use the CGEventPostToPSN method to send the keystrokes. My problem is that I need the PSN for it, but all the solutions I could find in Stackoverflow use an iteration over the processes using GetNextProcess and it seems to be deprecated.

Is there a way of getting the PSN from a process if a know the name of the application or the path?

Or is there any other way of sending keystrokes to an external app? I could imagine that in any case I will need a PSN or a pid to the process.

It would be great to get Objective C code for it.

Comment: Use `NSRunningApplication`, `processIdentifier` and `CGEventPostToPid`?

Comment: Thank you very much @Willeke. I found something similar and I use 
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.frontmostApplication.processIdentifier to get the pid for the front most application. Then it is just a matter of using CGEventPostToPid. Probably quite obvious for you, but i am new to programming for MacOS after 30+ years of Windows.
I will take a look at NSRunningApplication.

Answer (score 0):

To get the PSN, you can use `OSStatus GetProcessForPID(pid_t pid, ProcessSerialNumber *psn)` from the HIServices Framework. It's been deprecateded for many years but it still works fine.

In newer APIs there is the `LSASN` (LS stands for LaunchServices, I don't know what ASN means). Despite the different name it's exactly the same as the ProcessSerialNumber and can be used interchangeably.

`NSRunningRunningApplication` has a private `_asn` field which contains the LSASN. But it's wrapped inside an opaque CFType and I don't know how to extract the content except by parsing the result of `CFCopyDescription()`. Other ways to get the ASN are the `lsappinfo` command line tool or the private LaunchServices APIs. But none of those methods are great.

Personally, I would just stick to using `GetProcessForPID()` until it's removed from the sytem. It's been deprecated since macOS 10.10 which was released in late 2014 - so over 9 years ago! But it still works fine.